# Can't find Python executable even if the variable is previously set

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I'm trying an npm install in a proyect and I recieve this error:

```
C:\Users\irodriba\Documents\project\node_modules\iconv>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:Usersirodriba.windows-build-toolspython27python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npm-lifecycle\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\irodriba\Documents\project\node_modules\iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v8.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@12.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.9.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@12.1.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-import@^2.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package babel-preset-env is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iconv@2.3.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@2.3.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\irodriba\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-30T15_39_27_535Z-debug.log
```

I tried to set the variable in the environment variables and manually with the command:

```
npm config set python C:\Users\irodriba\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
```

The executable is in the specified path but it doesn't work. The error seems to disappear all the "" joining the entire path without folder separations.

I tried the npm install in a powershell instead of a git bash console and i get a different error:

```
C:\Users\irodriba\Documents\project\node_modules\iconv>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\irodriba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1745) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2013
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\irodriba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\irodriba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at regSearchKeys (C:\Users\irodriba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at regGetValue (C:\Users\irodriba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\irodriba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:288:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\irodriba\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\irodriba\Documents\project\node_modules\iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v8.16.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@12.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.9.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@12.1.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-import@^2.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package babel-preset-env is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iconv@2.3.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@2.3.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-01T08_05_55_847Z-debug.log
```

Comment: `pyhton.exe`? Is that a typo in your question, or an actual typo? It's `python.exe`.

Comment: Given the lack of backslashes in the error output (third line), you may need to double the backslashes in your path setting, or quote the path.

Comment: Ideally, you should be using Python3

Comment: The python.exe was just a typo in the question. Sorry about that. And the double backlashes or quoting the path it doesn't work either. And in the proyet i am in, i can't use Python3. I tried the npm install command in a powershell, instead of a git bash console and i get a different error.